# data-service Compiling and running versions greater than 0.18.1

Tags: wavesplatform

I can't start the API starting from version 0.18.1. Example version 0.20.0 I get an error:

/home/ubuntu/data-service/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:261
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes)
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/index.ts(15,34): error TS2497: This module can only be referenced with ECMAScript imports/exports by turning on the 'esModuleInterop' flag and referencing its default export.
src/index.ts(26,35): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ expose: string; header: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ expose?: string | undefined; header?: string | undefined; query?: string | undefined; }'.
  Types of property 'header' are incompatible.
    Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.

I tried different versions in different variants. But the errors are almost the same.
what versions and what do you use for compilation? Maybe I am launching wrong?
There is one nuance that makes me roll back to jest@23.6.0
Because it is needed for ts-jest.
How correct?

Comment: Take a survey on how to ask a question and format it well. it is hard to understand your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't actually use ts-node to launch the app. One of the reasons we've stopped using it is that it sometimes produces cryptic errors even when the `tsc` compiles fine.

Try launching this way (requires ENV vars):

```
npm run build
node dist/index.js
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're using an old version of TS.

We use:

ts-node 7.0.1

typescript 3.2.2

Comment: I still can not run. ./node_modules/.bin/ts-node -v
ts-node v7.0.1
node v8.10.0
typescript v3.2.2 and i try to run: export $(cat variables.env | xargs) && NODE_ENV=production ./node_modules/.bin/ts-node src/index.ts